# How to call derived class virtual method from another derived class object

Tags: c#, oop, virtual

Below mentioned scenario will clear the situation in a good manner. I am willing to call xDerived1 class virtual method. Although I am able to call xBase class method and xDerived2 class method.

((xDerived1)xDer2).myMethod(); //override void myMethod

Please help me out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            xDerived2 xDer2 = new xDerived2();
            xDer2.myMethod();
            ((xBase)xDer2).myMethod();
            ((xDerived1)xDer2).myMethod();
}


public class xBase
        {
            public virtual void myMethod()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("virtual void myMethod");
            }
        }
    public class xDerived1 :xBase
    {
        public new virtual void myMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("new virtual void myMethod");
        }
    }
    public class xDerived2 : xDerived1
    {
        public override void myMethod()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("override void myMethod");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem, we can call it by using reflection as mentioned below:

```
xDerived2 child = new xDerived2();

            Action parentPrint = (Action)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Action), child, typeof(xDerived1).GetMethod("myMethod").MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer());
            parentPrint.Invoke();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is simply not possible to call `xDerived1::myMethod` from an instance of `xbase`.  The `new` keyword causes a new method to be defined hence `xDerived::myMethod` is completely separate from `xbase::myMethod`.  In order to call the method you will need to cast down to `xDerived1`.

```
xbase local1 = ...;
xDerived1 local2 = local1 as xDerived;
if (local2 != null) { 
  local2.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: I wanted to conform: since myMethod() is overridden in xDerived2, and it is virtual in xDerived1, assuming 'new' keyword is NOT used, is ti possible to call xDerived1::myMethod() ?